# How to write an SQL query in query CI syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have below query, which I need to write in Model of Codeignitor

```
SELECT DISTINCT make FROM equipment_nonconnected_master WHERE Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID IN (select Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID FROM equipment_nonconnected_type_master)
```

I am only aware of the select query simply written in Codeignitor as given below:

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('make');
$this->db->order_by('make', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get('carriermodels');
```

Can someone help me writing the Query in CI syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by using simple `where()` function

```
$subquery="SELECT 
    Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID 
  FROM
    equipment_nonconnected_type_master";
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('make');
$this->db->from('carriermodels');
$this->db->where('Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID IN('.$subquery.')');
$this->db->order_by('make', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Or better to use join

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('c.make');
$this->db->from('carriermodels c');
$this->db->join('equipment_nonconnected_type_master m','c.Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID =m.Equipment_NonConnected_Type_Master_ID ');
$this->db->order_by('c.make', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Don't forget at the end to do a `return $query`